# HTTP request from a url to HOLOLENS 2

Tags: hololens

I'm trying to make an http request to a server, on unity it doesn't give errors but on hololens it doesn't work. It lags a lot but it doesn't work. In particular I'm trying to send a string in base 64 and then translate it back. Using a local server and an external Unity server doesn't cause any problems. However, it doesn't work in Hololens.
Suggestions?

```
` 
 void Update()
 {
    chiamataIMAGE();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
 }
 // Decodifica la stringa da base64 a una Texture2D (la stringa rappresenta un'immagine)
 public Texture2D Decode(string input)
 {
    byte[] img = System.Convert.FromBase64String(input);
    Texture2D txt = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    txt.LoadImage(img);
    return txt;
 }
 // Inserisce la Texture2D in un nuovo materiale
 public Material MaterialWithTexture(Texture2D texture) {
    Material material = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));
    material.mainTexture = texture;
    return material;
 }
 async void chiamataIMAGE()
 {
        try
    {
        // Creo un'istanza di HttpClient
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Imposto l'indirizzo del server
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:3000");

            // Creo un'istanza di HttpResponseMessage
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            // Eseguo la chiamata GET
            response = await client.GetAsync("/immagine");

            // Leggo il contenuto della risposta
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            // Applica il materiale con l'immagine all'imageQuad
            MeshRenderer quadRenderer = imageQuad.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
            if (quadRenderer == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Il GameObject deve avere un componente MeshRenderer.");
                return;
            }
            quadRenderer.material = MaterialWithTexture(Decode(content));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
             Debug.LogError("Errore durante la chiamata API: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
`
```

Comment: From you code snippet, you are trying to access the local loopback address (127.0.0.0) with HttpClient from your HoloLens app. Please note HoloLens apps are UWP apps. And by default, UWP applications aren't allowed to receive loopback traffic. For more details, please see [network isolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh770532(v=win.10)) & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#debugging-options.